# how to pre-process a PHP MVC view without using the framework?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, include, output-buffering

Is there any way I can pre-process a PHP view script without using a particular MVC framework?

Basically I want to render the view and pass it as an HTML string to another view.  The view I'm trying to render has some references like $this->rows, and, of course, I would need to add the values of those references to the script before generating the HTML.

Is this possible?

Comment: You might want to provide more information, such as the MVC framework.

Comment: @justin, he want to implement the mvc patterns himself, that's why he needed a technique to capture the output buffer...

Comment: Yes, I purposely left out the MVC framework (which happens to be Joomla).  I'm interested in seeing if I can do this in a framework agnostic manner - which I think would be very cool because then I could potentially recycle views from other frameworks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is completely possible.  You'll want to utilize [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to ensure the initial view isn't displayed and then store that views output in a variable.

```
ob_start();
include ('/path/to/file.php');
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: But how would I add data to the included file before rendering it?  The included view file has references like $this->rows that I want to change.

Comment: I guess I can add the variables to my context before I include my view - but for some reason ob_end_clean() is not "silently discarding my buffer contents."  As soon as I include by view file it is sent to output, whether it's in the buffer or outside.

Comment: Well, correction, ob_end_clean() does silently discard my buffer contents if the contents are not an include - but the include outputs regardless.  Any way to prevent that?

Comment: Found the problem!  The buffer wont stop a fatal error from puking everything to output!

Comment: Everything is working perfectly - beautiful - this is a huge discovery for me.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it depends on the framework you're using.

But this can be done with PHP by just using nested includes.

For example

page.php

```
<?php include(HEADER) ?>

<?= $var ?>

<?php include(FOOTER) ?>
```

All variables available to page.php will be available to the header and footer views as well.

Comment: I'm using Joomla.  The problem is I need to pre-process page.php and turn it into a string.  And I need to change the value of $var before I do that.  So, if the file were an object, I would want something like this: page.php->var = "foo" - and then get render the page into a string with the assigned values.